# How can you close a tokio-postgres connection?

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-tokio, tokio-postgres

In the `tokio-postgres` [documentation](https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/0.7.1/tokio_postgres/) in the first example, there is an example showing that you should run the database connection in a separate thread:

```rust
// The connection object performs the actual communication with the database,
// so spawn it off to run on its own.
tokio::spawn(async move {
    if let Err(e) = connection.await {
        eprintln!("connection error: {}", e);
    }
});
```

If you do so, how can you kill that connection afterwards?

Comment: "Connection implements Future, and only resolves when the connection is closed, either because a fatal error has occurred, or because its associated Client has dropped and all outstanding work has completed" so the connection is closed automatically when the client is dropped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on `tokio` 1, `tokio::task::JoinHandle` has an [abort()](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.5.0/tokio/task/struct.JoinHandle.html#impl) function that cancels the task, thus dropping the connection.

```
let handle = task::spawn(async move {
    if let Err(e) = connection.await {
        eprintln!("connection error: {}", e);
    }
}
handle.abort(); // this kills the task and drops the connection
```

Using my snippet as-is will immediately kill the task, thus this is probably not what you want in the end, but if you keep the `handle` around and use it e.g. in combination with some kind of shutdown listener you should be able to control the connection as wanted.